# Face ID got error -1004 when install both app with same target name

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-id, biometrics, face-id

I build both apps from the same project but change bundle identifier.
They are the same target name (product name).
So one of them can't using Face ID or Touch ID, the fail one got error code -1004 from LAContext.

Is there any documentation from Apple or anyone could explain ?

(Both working fine with difference target name)